# Repeat terminal command until specified output

Tags: command-line, bash, dropbox

I would like to define an alias that performs a command every x seconds until an underlying process gives a designated output. Then, the command should stop being run.

Is this possible, and if so, how?
Help is much appreciated.

I'm almost satisfied with

```
alias test1='while true; do <command>; sleep 1; done'
```

except I have to manually stop it, and can therefore not make it execute a new command once finished.

**The reason for the question:**
Dropbox synchronizes poorly at work. Sometimes, I have to restart it. I would like to do that using a command which also tells when the sync is done, e.g. by

```
alias drop='dropbox stop && dropbox start && while true; do dropbox status; sleep 1; done'
```

I would like the repetition stopped when Dropbox outputs 'Up to date'.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Set a condition for the while loop

If you replace

```
while true
```

by:

```
while [ "$(dropbox status)" != "Up to date" ]
```

it works as you describe.

#### The command

To stop/start `Dropbox` and finish after synchronizing is done becomes then:

```
dropbox stop && dropbox start && while  [ "$(dropbox status)" != "Up to date" ]; do dropbox status; sleep 1; done
```

*Or better* (to prevent doubling `dropbox status`):

```
dropbox stop && dropbox start && while  [ "$(dropbox status)" != "Up to date" ]; do echo "Updating"; sleep 1 ; done && echo "Finished"
```

*Explanation*

`while true` is waiting for a break condition inside the loop (which never comes), but `while [ "$(dropbox status)" != "Up to date"` makes the loop break *if* `dropbox status` returns `Up to date`

Comment: Thank you! I've opted for you're first suggestion --- I like the explicit status it provides.

Comment: @Rasmus Always happy if it works :)

Answer (score 6):

As Jacob says, use the condition on the loop. I suggest an `until` loop:

```
dropbox stop && dropbox start && 
until dropbox status | grep -q "Up to date";
do 
  sleep 1; 
done
```

`until` runs until the command returns true, that's when `dropbox status` output contains `Up to date`.

Comment: Thank you, muru! The usage of 'until' command in combination with 'grep' is very informative. I'm sure it will come in handy for other things --- for now, I've opted for Jacob's first solution, as I like the explicit status it provides.

Comment: @Rasmus sure. :) Just a note: you can use the same test `[ "$(dropbox status)" != "Up to date" ]` with `until` - just replace `!=` with `=`. Essentially `until` is `while` with engation.

Comment: Again, thank you! I just changed things around to try it out. I'm clapping my hands -- this is a very fun way to learn things!

Comment: wouldn't `dropbox status | grep -q "Up to date";` make the complete script to fail with `set -e`?

Comment: @sumek `set -e` doesn't affect commands in the condition of `if`, `while`, etc. If it did, that would make it rather useless.

Answer (score 1):

Define it as a function in your `$HOME/.bashrc`

```
syncDropBox()
{
dropbox stop && \
dropbox start && 
while true; 
do 
  STAT="$(dropbox status)"
  if [ "$STAT" = "Up to date"  ] ; then
  break # or add more commands to finilize the process
  fi
  sleep 1; 
done
}
```

Now, I don't have `dropbox` cmd app, so depending on the way it outputs status, you may or may not process it with `AWK` or `grep`.

But point being that you can either store output to value or redirect output to another command, and evaluate them. Once we get specific output string - break

Comment: Thank you, Serg. This is an interesting alternative to defining an alias and it works like a charm.